# I want to read file and write another file. Basically, I want to do some arithmetic and write few other columns

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a file like

```
2.0 4 3
0.5 5 4
-0.5 6 1
-2.0 7 7
.......
```

the actual file is pretty big

which I want to read and add couple of columns, first added column, `column(4) = column(2) * column(3)` and 2nd column added would be `column 5 = column(2)/column(1) + column(4)` so the result should be

```
2.0 4 3 12 14
0.5 5 4 20 30
-0.5 6 1 6 -6
-2.0 7 7 49 45.5
.....
```

which I want to write in a different file.

```
with open('test3.txt', encoding ='latin1') as rf: 
     with open('test4.txt', 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            float_list= [float(i) for i in line.split()]
            print(float_list)
```

But so far I just have this. I am just able create the list not sure how to perform arithmetic on the list and create new columns. I think I am completely off here. I am just a beginner in python. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you have new value at rthe end of line so append new values to the list `float_list.append()`.  And later use `' '.join()` to generate line. Or use `csv` module with space as separator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: How would you suggest I do that? I very new to python as well as programming in general. If you could be specific that would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reuse your formulae, but shifting indexes since they start at 0 in python.
I would extend the read `column` list of floats with the new computations, and write back the line, space separated (converting back to `str` in a list comprehension)

So, the inner part of the loop can be written as follows:

```
with open('test3.txt', encoding ='latin1') as rf:
     with open('test4.txt', 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:    
           column= [float(i) for i in line.split()]  # your code
           column.append(column[1] * column[2])  # add column
           column.append(column[1]/column[0] + column[3])  # add another column
           wf.write(" ".join([str(x) for x in column])+"\n")  # write joined  strings, separated by spaces
```

Comment: Fabre: Thanks for the reply. This worked fine. Only problem I had is that it would skip very first line. Would you like to comment on that? Thanks again!

Comment: This would consume 1st and 2nd lines. is there way not to consume any of the lines?

Comment: sorry, I misread. I don't see why it would consume the first line: open the file, iterate on the lines. It does not skip any line. It's not logical. Check your input file again.

Comment: I found my mistake. Sorry for wasting your time. I had "for line in rf:" twice in the code itself. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - see comments in code

```
with open('test3.txt', encoding ='latin1') as rf: 
     with open('test4.txt', 'w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            float_list = [float(i) for i in line.split()]

            # calculate two new columns
            float_list.append(float_list[1] * float_list[2])
            float_list.append(float_list[1]/float_list[0] + float_list[3])

            # convert all values to text
            text_list =  [str(i) for i in float_list]

            # concatente all elements and write line
            wf.write(' '.join(text_list) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

[`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is used to convert each element of the list to `float`, by the end it is used again to convert each `float` to `str` so we can concatenate them.

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out: 
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            my_list = map(float, line.split())
            my_list.append(my_list[1]*my_list[2])
            my_list.append(my_list[1] / my_list[0] + my_list[3])
            my_list = map(str, my_list)
            out.write(' '.join(my_list) + '\n')
```

Comment: won't work in python 3 because `map` returns an iterator, not a list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Python 3 is not tagged in this question. If the code is Python 3, I think the OP should specify that.